# Autohotkey Click and hold RMB+W macro

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a macro that clicks and holds "W" key and "RMB" when "RMB" is being held.
So far I've came up with something like this:

```
RButton::
    if( not GetKeyState("RButton" , "P") )
    Click, down, right
    Send {w down}
return
RButton Up::
    Click, up, right
    Send {w up}
```

This only holds "W" key, but not "RMB".
I would appreciate some help.

RMB - Right mouse button

Comment: Hi! Just to help other contributors understand how to replicate and understand your problem (as well as find your problem!) you might want to add some details like the programming language you are using, what 'RMB' means, and things of that nature.

Comment: Have you tried using the tilde `~` modifier symbol? https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols Also, your title asks about the left and middle mouse buttons, but your actual question is about the right mouse button and W... that's... confusing?

Comment: @EJE Yes! Thank you! I've added "~" at the beginning of the first line and the script works flawlessly.